# LInked list not reversing

Tags: c++, linked-list

Bellow, I have some code that is supposed to display a linked list, reverse it, and then display the now reversed linked list, but it seems that it never displays. My only guess is that somehow the linked list is becoming null. What am I doing wrong? Both the reverse function and the function that should display the reversed array run, but there is no visual output after.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:// creation of a simple Node class
  int data;
  Node* next;
  
};

class LinkedList{
public:
  Node* head;
  LinkedList() { head = NULL; }

  void append( int x){
    Node* temp = new Node;// allocate new node
    Node* end = head;//used later
  
    temp->data = x;//giving the node data
    temp->next = NULL;//since this node will be last make the next of it NULL
  
    if(head == NULL){// if list is empty then set new Node as the head
      head = temp;
      return;
    }
    while(end->next != NULL){// go until the last node
      end = end->next;
    }
    end->next = temp;// change the next of the last node to the new node.
  }
  void reverse(){
    Node* current = head;
    Node* next = NULL;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    
    while(current != NULL){
      next = current->next;// Store next

      current->next = prev;// Reverse current node's pointer
  
      prev = current;// Move pointers one position ahead.
      current = next;
    }
    
    head = prev;
  }

  void display(){
    while(head != NULL){// print data while not out of bounds
      cout<<" "<<head->data;
      head = head->next;
    }
  }
};





int main() {
  LinkedList list;
  list.append(1);
  list.append(10);
  list.append(32);
  list.append(64);
  list.append(102);
  list.append(93);
  list.display();
  cout<<endl;
  list.reverse();
  cout<<"list reversed"<<endl;
  list.display();
  cout<<"reverse display ran"<<endl;
```

Comment: A debugger is a great tool to use to figure these things out. Step through the code and see if what is happening is what you expect. My advice is start with a smaller list, 3 nodes is enough, and sequential numbers. You should take a close look at the `display()` function. You shouldn't be modifying `head` in it. By the time you get to `reverse()` in your code `head` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was an oversight on my part, I should have set up a temporary variable that represented the head, in my current program I'm changing what head references in order to loop through the linked list, and thus setting head equal to null once it reaches the end of the list a correct way to write the display function would be:

```cpp
  void display(){
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){// print data while not out of bounds
      cout<<" "<<temp->data;
      temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
```

thanks to user [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) for reminding me that debuggers exist.